# FB.ui() with method: "feed" is broken

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, feed, fb.ui

It seems that method: 'feed' within FB.ui() using FB JavaScript SDK is broken. Consider the following example:

- Having an app running as Page Tab on a FB page AND Canvas-App
- All needed fields in the app section are filled out correctly
- Using FB.ui() with method: 'feed' to let a user tell someone about it
- The link-Property of method: 'feed' is set the Canvas-URL and for testing to the Page Tab URL of the app
- Everything worked for us until a few days ago (don't remember the exact day)
- Debugged over and over and couldn't find a bug

We always get the following error, **now even with apps that formerly worked**:

"An error occurred with xxx. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application."

Comment: [http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/488243747855568](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/488243747855568)

Answer (score 0):

At least you got an error message.
I've the same but the following : 
"An error occurred with xxx. Please try again later."
No error code or something.

Did you changed something on your app config ?
Your error code might means :

- bad redirect_uri (mb you hav'nt the same appId or something)
- You just changed your app domain name and your redirect uri isn't in the same domain

Try to access your app with your redirect_uri, if an error shows up you need to fix your redirect.

Good luck !